# Another Division Algorithm Question.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if a,b,c are integers, with b > 0 and c >0, such that when a is divided by b, the quotient is q and the remainder is r, and when q is divided by c, the quotient is t and the remainder is s, then when a is divided by bc, the quotient is t and the remainder is bs + r.

so, a = bq + r and q = ct + s.

and i can re-arrange the second equation to get;

$c = \frac{q-s}{t} $

plugging this into $a = (bc)q + r$

$a = b\frac{q-s}{t}q + r  $

I feel as though i am chasing a lie.

The plugging part is where it all goes wrong i think.

Comment: sorry, that was an error on my part.

Comment: No rearrangement required... $a=b(ct+s)+r = (bc)t + (bs+r)$

Comment: i am ashamed. Thanks.

Comment: For the answer to be complete, you need to show that $0\le bs+r<bc$.

Comment: Don't forget that you also need to show that $0\le bs+r<bc$ given $0\le r<b$ and $0\le s<c$, but this is easy.

Comment: i am unsure how to obtain this inequality :(. so frustrating.

Comment: i have multiplied $ 0 \leq s < c$ through by b, then where do i go from there?

Comment: I put it together as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the formulas straightforwardly, $$a=b(ct+s)+r=(bc)t+(bs+r)$$

In order for $t$ to be regarded as the quotient, however, we also need $bs+r<bc$. From the earlier definitions, we know that $b>r$ and $c>s$. From this we can say that 
$$ \begin{align}c &\geq s+1 \\  bc &\geq bs+b \\ bc &> bs+r \end{align}$$
as required.